# How can I add info from one row to another row multiple times before a specific word?

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv, python-re

Suppose I have a table as following:

```
ID             Description
1           code: xyz; code:axy
2      code: 238a; code: 34u; code: 482m
3             code: 24sd
4         code: 3edn; code: 3n23
```

And I want the following table:

```
ID            Description
1              code: xyz
1              code: axy
2              code: 238a
2              code: 34u
2              code: 482m
3              code: 24sd
4              code: 3edn
4              code: 3n23
```

My actual code:

```
for line in fhand["Description"]:
    x = line.replace(";" , ",")
    y = txt.replace("code", [fhand['Id'] + "code"])
```

But, as you can imagine, it is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (I'm assuming your DataFrame is named `fhand`, as in your code example):

```
fhand['Description'] = fhand['Description'].str.split(';')
fhand = fhand.explode('Description')
```

**EDIT**: You might want to add an `lstrip` afterwards:

```
fhand['Description'] = fhand['Description'].str.lstrip()
```

Result:

```
    Description
ID             
1     code: xyz
1      code:axy
2    code: 238a
2     code: 34u
2    code: 482m
3    code: 24sd
4    code: 3edn
4    code: 3n23
```

(In your example `code:axy` has no blank behind the ":": Is that accidental?)

Comment: Thank you so much, Timus! You really helped me and I got the result that I wanted. It's my first time using stack overflow and my first time asking for help using python. I'm a beginner. :)